# The EXACT same code doesn't work as it should in Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver

Sometimes when I copy javascript from jsfiddle into Dreamweaver I end up banging my head in the wall. Two documents with (what looks to be) the EXACT same javascript doesn't work in the same way.

In document A I have the following code:

```
<script>
alert('test')
</script>
```

In document B I have the following code (does not work):

```
<script>
alert('test')
​</script>
```

Note: Please copy code B in to a html document and try if it alert before giving me comments. I am not joking, there is something weird going on.

I have located the problem to be something with the end script tag, but I can't see any thing wrong with the code.

Whats the difference in the code from document A and B?

Comment: Have you tried adding in the type?  `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: Nick, please try copy code to a document and try. Does it work for you? :)

Comment: Add a semicolon after alert('test')

Comment: Located the problem better. The code in document B seams to contain some Unicode characters. Hmmmm!

Comment: how did you 'locate' the problem?

Comment: @DaveB That isn't necessary in js.

Comment: I located the Unicode characters by copying the code from example B into notepad instead of dreamweaver. When saving the document into a html file I got the alert. I was only alerted when saving the document with ANSI coding. It's not alerting any errors when saving as utf-8...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got an [Zero-width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) (U+8203) behind the closing bracket.

The bug [is known to jsfiddle](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-docs-alpha/issues/163), it seems to be an issue with the [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/) syntax highlighter.

Comment: How did you locate it? The OP says an alert came up when trying to save in Notepad. I've seen the same thing myself when copying code from JSFiddle and I get an alert when saving in Emacs pointing where the offending character is. Do you have a better approach?

Comment: I copied the string into the console, did a `.split("")` on it and then looked up the `.getCharCode()` at the position of the empty string. I did not copy the code to a editor, I suspected a invisible character right away when reading about the OPs problem - the code looks quite the same.

Answer (score 2):

When copy and pasting the javascript code from jsfiddle (using Chrome browser) into Dreamweaver I get a invisable Unicode charactar at the end of the script.

This little one: "​" (yes there is a character between those...)

This mess up the javascript and it is hard to locate the problem.

If you have a similar problem as mine you can search for the character by copying it from the "" above.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Test");
</script>
```

HTH

Comment: that isn't necessary anymore since HTML5 came.

Comment: type="text/javascript" is not needed in HTML5 :)

Comment: Sorry, the tag your using is 'HTML' not 'HTML5'.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you put this code in the page ?

Try using `<script type="text/javascript">` instead of just `<script>`.

In order to work, you script need to be anywhere between `<head></head>` or `<body></body>`.

Have you try another browser ? Are you sure Javascript is enabled ?

Comment: that isn't necessary anymore since HTML5 came.

Comment: type="text/javascript", <head>, </head>, <body>, </body> are all optional i HTML5 if done correctly :)

Comment: @user1087110 and is the doctype of your dreamweaver document also html5?

Comment: I have tried <!DOCTYPE html> as well. That's not the problem... :(

Comment: Did you look at Javascript's debug system inside your browser ?